# Filter specific data from a nested array object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to write a recursive method that will filter out only those data which don't have a complete object or a string. Take as below example -

```
const userParticalData = {
    student: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'sankhnad',
        mobile: 1111111111
    },
    resultId: 1,
    address: [
        {
            id: 1,
            state: 'delhi',
            pin: 102202
        },
        {
            id: 2
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            aname: 'assam',
            pin: 102202
        }
    ],
    streem: [
        {
            id: 1,
            state: 'CA',
            place: 'campus'
        }
    ]
};
```

Now the output would be for the above -

```
const output = {
    resultId: 10,
    address: [
        {
            id: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

So, if we compare the result, the **resultId** is not an **object**, and inside **address** the **id: 2** only has 1 data which is incomplete. So, we need to find only those objects with only one element and also those elements whose value is only string.

I have tried below solution -

```
function filtereMappedData (leafData, initialData, primaryKey) {
    let rootKey = primaryKey;
    return _.each(leafData, (element, key) => {
        if (_.isObject(element) && _.size(element) > 1 && element['id']) {
            if (_.isString(key)) {
                rootKey = key;
            }
            delete initialData[rootKey];
            return initialData;
        }

        if (_.isArray(element)) {
            return filtereMappedData(element, initialData, key);
        }
        return initialData;
    });
}


const output = filtereMappedData(userParticalData, userParticalData);
```

I'm getting this as a output =

```
{
    resultId: 1
}
```

Comment: this would be a nested method. So the best would be recursive. Any solution would be appreciated even without recursion.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve, would you explain it better and share you attempt? what did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: I have added the possible solution